# Need assistance with SQL statement having trouble with the JOINS and WHERE clause

Tags: sql, join, oracle-apex, where-clause

The company is performing an analysis of their inventory. They are considering purging books that are not popular with their customers. To do this they need a list of books that have never been purchased. Write a query using a join that provides this information. Your results should include all the book details and the order number column. Sort your results by the book title.

```
 SELECT o.order_nbr, b.*
 FROM orders o JOIN books 
 WHERE 
 ORDER BY book_title
```

This is all I could come up with, I'm still learning Joins and struggling to figure out what the correct statement should be. Wasn't sure what to put in the WHERE clause and don't really know how to properly join these tables.

Comment: Your "I'm lost" is not clear, please edit to clarify. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research.. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Comment: Don't edit your question in response to an answer post. Leave it as a question. The answer is in an answer post & you showed it was helpful by accepting it by clicking on the check mark. If you find an answer yourself, post your own answer post & after minimum wait time you can accept it. I have rolled back your edit. But please edit your post to ask a clear specific researched non-duplicate question per earlier comments. PS Please don't put something only in the title. [ask] [answer] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `ON` clause to specify what you are joining on. Also, your `WHERE` clause is empty, and you are not specifying the type of `JOIN` you are using. Looking at the way the tables are set up, the expectation is you are going to join the `BOOKS` table on `ORDER_ITEMS`, which also contains `ORDER_NBR`.

In the question, it's asking to find books with no orders, so correct join would be a `LEFT JOIN` between `BOOKS` and `ORDER_ITEMS`, as that will include every book, even those without orders, which will have an `ORDER_NBR` of `NULL`

The SQL would look like

```
SELECT o.order_nbr, b.*
 FROM books b
 LEFT JOIN order_items o on b.book_id = o.book_id
 WHERE o.order_nbr is null
 ORDER BY book_title
```

This would return only the books with no orders.

Comment: Just asking, this worked of course but I was interested in what would happen if I put FULL JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN and got same results.  Is that normal?  I'm still learning all these different joins

Comment: Yes a FULL JOIN would also work; in this example books LEFT JOIN order_items join the two tables but also keep any books that have no orders_items to match on. a FULL JOIN will keep any books that have no order_items but also any order_items that have no books. I specified LEFT JOIN because we are only interested in books that have no matching order_items, so the FULL JOIN is not as optimized